# How do i fix SSL Security error on Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, windows-server-2019

I have app server(windows server 2016) where Crystal Report 2011 is installed and DB server(Windows Server 2019) where SQL Server 2019 is installed. I have created a new blank Crystal Report on my app server then trying to add new OLE DB(ADO) connection with
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server to my DB Server, but it is failing with following error

> Logon failed.
> Details: ADO Error Code: 0x80004005
> Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
> Description: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security error.
> SQL State: 08001
> Native Error: 18 [Database Vendor Code: 18 ]

I tried disabling TLS 1.2 and enabled TLS 1.0 on both source and destination machines still it is throwing same error.
I also tried installing new OLEDB driver from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver19
Still issue persists.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: As with the JDBC, ODBC and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient drivers OLE DB got updated to use connection encryption by default. Have a read through [Encryption and certificate validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/encryption-and-certificate-validation) to see what connection properties you need to change - and why.